# checking of correctness of excel program for F test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, excel

i would like to express my doubt about  F test performed by Analysis toolpak , let us consider following link

[F Test in excel](https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/f-test.html)

everything seems  ok until calculation of one tail critical value, generally for two tailed test alpha is divided into 2, in this case $\alpha=0.05$ and  its half would bee  $\alpha/2=0.025$(both left and right right) and for two tailed test  right   critical value is taken, because Df  are  5 and 4, in excel critical value for right part would be

```
=F.INV.RT(0.025,5,4)
```

which is  equal to  9.364470816, but  excel give us value 6.256056502, which is simple critical value for right  tail test , not  two tailed test, it  can be verified by  following command

```
=F.INV.RT(0.05,5,4)
```

am i right? i think that excel program does not support two tailed test right?

Comment: Think about what a two-tailed F test would mean.  In most circumstances it's not relevant.

Comment: i have checked F test  using other online calculator  as well   http://www.statskingdom.com/220VarF2.html , that  would confirm  there is mistake  on first link

Comment: if he is conducting one tail test  than he should mention about this, but critical values for two tailed test is different from critical value  of one tailed test  ,

Comment: for instance if  we  analyze  two tailed test,  we get that variances  are equal(we dont have  enough evidence to reject  null hypothesis), if  we perform right tail test( variance of females  are greater than variance of male)then we reject null hypothesis, at the same time how it can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Right-sided alternative:** The sample variance for females is $S_f^2 = 160$ and the
sample variance for males is $S_m^2 = 21.7.$

In R, the test of $H_0: \sigma_f^2/\sigma_m^2 = 1$ against $H_a: \sigma_f^2/\sigma_m^2 > 1$ gives the following result.

```
f = c(26,25,43,34,18,52);  m = c(23,30,18,25,28)
var.test(f, m, alt="g")   # 'g' for 'greater'

        F test to compare two variances

data:  f and m
F = 7.3733, num df = 5, denom df = 4, p-value = 0.03789
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is greater than 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 1.178581      Inf
sample estimates:
ratio of variances 
          7.373272
```

***P-value as rejection criterion:*** So even though sample sizes are small, the sample variance for females is
sufficiently larger than the sample variance for males to reject $H_0$ at the
5% level; the P-value is 0.038 < 0.05.

This P-value can be computed in R as follows:

```
1 - pf(7.3733, 5, 4)
[1] 0.03788813
```

***Critical value as rejection criterion:*** The 5% critical value for this one-sided test is the number $c$ such that $P(F > c) = 0.95,$ so that $c = 6.2561.$ Using this critical value, we reject $H_0$ because the observed variance ratio $7.3733 > 6.2561.$

```
qf(.95, 5, 4)
[1] 6.256057
```

A plot of the density function of the distribution $\mathsf{F}(5,4)$ is shown below. The observed variance ratio is at the vertical blue line. The P-value
of the one-sided test is the area beneath the density curve to right of this line. The critical value $c=6.2521$ is shown by the vertical red dotted line; the are to the right of this line is $0.05.$

[image]

Using software, it is more common to use the P-value of the test, rejecting
$H_0$ at the 5% level, if the P-value is less than 5%.

**Two-sided alternative:** If you are doing a two-sided test, it is customary to double the applicable P-value. (In this case
that's the P-value for the right-sided test because the variance ratio exceeds 1.) Then the two-sided P-value is taken to be $2(0.03789) = 0.07578,$ so you would *not* reject
doing a two-sided test. [Because the F-distribution is not symmetrical, it would be hard to say what value below 0 would be 'as extreme as' 7.373272.]

In R, the P-value for a two-sided test agrees with this value. The output is
shown below, slightly abbreviated.

```
var.test(f, m, alt="t")   # 't' for 'two-sided'

        F test to compare two variances

data:  f and m
F = 7.3733, num df = 5, denom df = 4, p-value = 0.07578
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
...
```

***Critical values for two-sided test:*** Below is the density function of $\mathsf{F}(4,5)$ with dotted red lines
(at $0.1354$ and $9.3645$)
cutting off probability 0.025 from each tail of the distribution.

[image]

Notice that the variance ratio (heavy blue line) is between the two
critical values; accordingly, $H_0$ is not rejected against the two-sided alternative.

Comment: thank you ,   you confirmed  my  doubt  that  two tailed test in given link was mistake and actually it should be right  side test,  thanks

Comment: Nowadays, Excel is very much better at doing statistics than it was in the early days, but I find that the people who wrote some of the statistical functions in Excel think about things differently than I do, so I always check my Excel results agains software I understand better.

Comment: thank you for your help, by the way  we can write  our own functions in excel using VBA in order to  be sure that our result is  correct and reliable  , thanks man  wish you best

Answer (score 0):

If you read the example link carefully, even without any calculation, they are just inconsistent, switching from two tail to one tail ...

They started with two-tailed hypotheses: "**H1: σ<sup>2</sup><sub>1</sub>≠σ<sup>2</sup><sub>2</sub>**"
Then calculates the right-tailed test.

Finally, finished with the conclusion of the right-tailed test: "Conclusion: if F > FCritical **one-tail**, we reject the null hypothesis. This is the case, 7.373 > 6.256."